# IntelliJ setOnAction not recognized by ActionEvent library (JDK 8)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, java-8

I seem to have a problem with IntelliJ concerning the `setOnAction` lambda function. After lots of research I can not find an answer to my problem.

I'm learning to program in Java (latest JDK 8 version) and recently moved from NetBeans to IntelliJ IDE. I wrote a very simple program and the code works perfectly in NetBeans, but I have problems using IntelliJ.

The `setOnAction` function is not recognized by IntelliJ. I have configured the IDE (Project Structure/Modules/ and chose 8 - Lambda's, type annotations,...) but with no success. I manually added: `import javafx.event.ActionEvent;`

I have also configured (Settings/General/Auto Import/Add unambiguous imports on the fly).

The program contains two classes, a Main class and a GUI class.

Main class:

```
package fxvb0203;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class fxvb0203 extends Application
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage)
    {
       FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
       Scene scene = new Scene(root);

       new GUI(root);

       primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
       primaryStage.setScene(scene);
       primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

GUI class:

```
package fxvb0203;

import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.*;

public class GUI
{
    private final Button btnText = new Button("Text");
    private final TextField txtField = new TextField();

    public GUI(FlowPane pane)
    {
        btnText.setOnAction(event ->
        {
        txtField.setText("text");
        });

        pane.getChildren().add(btnText);
        pane.getChildren().add(txtField);
    }
}
```

`setOnAction` gives the following warning:

```
can not resolve method setOnAction, (lambda expression)
```

`import javafx.event.ActionEvent;` is greyed out as it is not used, which is strange. So it must be something with IntelliJ that is not correct.

Another small problem I have with IntelliJ only, but which does not relate to the main problem, is the following:

```
pane.getChildren().add(btnText);
pane.getChildren().add(txtField);
```

These two lines of code give the following error:

```
add (javafx.scene.Node) in list cannot be applied to (java.awt.TextField)
```

In NetBeans both work fine, but IntelliJ gives problems.

I hope to rely on the professional help of this community, because I am kinda stuck here and besides these small problems I really like the IntelliJ IDE.

Many thanks in advance.

Greets.

Comment: What is your project SDK set to.  It sounds like you set language level to Java 8 but are not using a Java 8 project SDK.

Comment: My SDK is set to 1.8. With the JDK home path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `GUI` class you have the following import statement: `import java.awt.*;`. The `*` means you're importing *everything* inside the `java.awt` package which includes (among others): `java.awt.TextField` and `java.awt.Button`.

What this means is that instead of `btnText` being a `javafx.scene.control.Button` it is actually a `java.awt.Button`. The AWT `Button` does not have a `setOnAction` method therefore you are getting a compilation error. This also affects your `txtField` which is now a `java.awt.TextField` instead of a `javafx.scene.control.TextField`.

Replace `import java.awt.*` with `import javafx.scene.control.Button` and `import javafx.scene.control.TextField`; *or* replace it with `import javafx.scene.control.*`.

In case importing `java.awt.*` was on purpose it is generally a bad idea to mix different GUI toolkits together.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. That seems to fix it. Thumbs up!  
java.awt.* was automatically added by IntelliJ.